# Retrieving known invalid XML via Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, xml, selenium

I have a Selenium test that needs to get some raw XML from a web server.  The problem I'm having is that one of the XML documents is known to be invalid because it is missing a root element.  I'd like get the raw source of the invalid XML and tack on my own root element, but every `WebDriver` flavor I've tried the attempting to parse the XML and returns some form of error message.  In short, I'm doing this:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();     
driver.get("http://some_URL_that_returns_xml_data");
String source = driver.getPageSource();
```

The `source` string represents the invalid XML error message rendered in the browser rather than the actual raw source as if I *viewed source* in the browser.

Does anyone know of a trick to get around this?

Comment: Selenium is the wrong tool for what you are trying to do. It's been too long since I've used Java so I can't be very specific but what you should do is use whatever library would allow you to perform an HTTP request directly to the server. There's no reason you can't both use Selenium and perform direct requests in the *same* test suite. I've done it in a Selenium test suite written in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way of doing this is to use [Apache HttpUtils](http://hc.apache.org/) package, and in your HTTP request, just push the correct Content-Type header, which is probably  **application/xml** .   Then, your response will be rendered by the browser as xml, rather than text or html.

If the XML is invalid, the browser might only render part of the document and so if you want all of the text, you might want to send content type of text in the request.

Answer (score 0):

If the only thing wrong with the XML is the absence of a wrapper element, then it is a "well-formed external parsed entity", and you can retrieve it using an entity reference. Create a dummy document like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE doc [
<!ENTITY e SYSTEM "http://uri.com/realdata.xml">
]>
<doc>&e;</doc>
```

(where the string after "SYSTEM" is the location of your XML), and pass this dummy document to your XML parser. (But not in the browser, where XML parsers typically ignore external entities).

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.tagname("body"));
String elHtml = element.getAttribute("innerHTML");
```

OR:

```
String elHtml = driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).getText()
```

Comment: I tried both of those with ChromeDriver and FirefoxDriver and I'm getting a `org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException` exception looking for "body".

Comment: sorry, forgot that xml has no body tag( then my answer becomes really not useful :)